# I get `""` (exact phrase) in mongodb query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I want to have a query that is word insensitive and case insensitive. I created the following query using `/.*#{params[:query]}*./i`:

```
def set_query
  @query = params[:query]
end

def set_documents
  @documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
  @documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
    :$text => {:$search => (/.*#{params[:query]}*./i).to_s}
  ) : @documents).page(params[:page])
end
```

But when I search, it is word sensitive: `rehabilitation` will give me documents that have `rehabilitation` in the title, but if I search with `rehab`, it won't give me anything.

I see that I get `""` inside the search term, which means `exact phrase` in mongodb, but idk [sic] why I get these `""` and how I can remove them.

```
"$text"=>{"$search"=>"(?i-mx:.*rehab*.)"},
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the same query without using to_s.

```
def set_documents
@documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
@documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
  :$text => {:$search => (/.*#{params[:query]}*./i)}
) : @documents).page(params[:page])
end
```

Comment: I had to put `to_s` because `$search` expects a `string`. Error: `$search" had the wrong type. Expected string, found regex (14)`